# How to compile data with spaces in DUST JS?

Tags: handlebars.js, dust.js

Anyone have experience with Dust JS? I'm having problems compiling templates with data which has spaces in some of the keys

JSON Data:

```
{"Street Address": "12 Coventry Road"}
```

Dust Template
    {Street Address}

Street Address never gets parsed :(

In Handlebars JS, you just wrap keys with spaces in square brackets but that doesnt seem to work in Dust JS

```
Eg {{[Street Address]}}
```

Anyway hoping someone can help, as I much prefer the functionality of Dust over Handlebars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dust.js Homepage:

> The Dust parser is finely tuned to minimize the amount of escaping that needs to be done within static text. Any text that does not closely resemble a Dust tag is considered static and will be passed through untouched to the template's output. This makes Dust suitable for use in templating many different formats. In order to be recognized as such, **Dust tags should not contain extraneous whitespace and newlines**.

Answer (score 0):

dust doesn't allow that because it is not a valid json. you should remove the WS.

TEMPLATE

```
{StreetAddress}
```

CONTEXT

```
{"StreetAddress": "12 Coventry Road"}
```

OUTPUT

```
12 Coventry Road
```

Anyway the dust repo is not being mantained. we have forked it and we are working on a lot of new features. Take a look:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs